# Callback function in two classes

Tags: c++, callback

Hello I have a problem with a callback function. I'm relative new to c++.
I have two classes helper and exporter:

**Helper:**

```
class Helper {
    typedef Bool (*IterationCallback)(BaseObject *op);
    public: Int32 RecurseHierarchy (BaseObject* op, IterationCallback callback) {
        Int32 count = 0;
        while (op) {
            if (callback(op)) {
                count++;
                count += RecurseHierarchy(op->GetDown(), callback);
                op = op->GetNext();
            }       
        }
        return count;
    }
};
```

**Exporter:**

```
class Exporter {
    private: Helper helper;

    private: Bool writeT3D (Filename exportT3D) {

        string filepath = C4DStringToStdString(exportT3D.GetString()); 
        t3DFile.open(filepath.c_str());
        writeBegin();

        // Iterate all objects in the document and writes an actor
        BaseDocument *doc = GetActiveDocument();

        Int32 count = helper.RecurseHierarchy(doc->GetFirstObject(), this->WriteActor);
        writeEnd();
        t3DFile.close();    

        return true;
    }
};
```

And I'm getting the error`C3867 function call missing argument list` and I should use `&Exporter::WriteActor`. But I can't solve the problem. Can someone help me?

Comment: What happened when you tried using `&Exporter::WriteActor`?

Comment: That seems to need some more information about your actual `Exporter` declaration.

Comment: Can't use it. Visual Studio tells me that the type ""Bool (Exporter::*)(BaseObject *op)"" is incompatible with the parameter of type ""IterationCallback""

Comment: What's `WriteAction`?

Comment: Firstly, you could have reduced the code by far, and you should have. Now, that said, you can't convert the expression `obj->function` to a function pointer, C++ simply doesn't support this. There is `std::function`, which allows you to achieve similar things, you will find examples online. Also check out the difference in C++ between a function and a memberfunction, understanding that is essential.

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem

Assuming `WriteActor` to be a member function of `Exporter`, then its type is probably:

```
Bool (Exporter::*)(BaseObject*)
```

which is not compatible with:

```
Bool (*)(BaseObject*)
```

The reason is that in the former an implicit parameter is passed of type `Exporter*` (normally accessible inside the member function as `this`), while in the latter this does not happen.

#### One solution

For the above reason, you need to explicitly pass this implicit argument of type `Exporter*`, before passing the resulting function to `RecurseHierarchy`.

In your case you can use `std::bind` as follows:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
auto fn = std::bind(&Exporter::WriterActor, this, _1);
Int32 count = helper.RecurseHierarchy(doc->GetFirstObject(), fn);
```

and then modify `Helper` to take any callable object:

```
struct Helper {
    template<typename Fn>
    Int32 RecurseHierarchy(BaseObject* op, Fn callback) {
        Int32 count = 0;
        while (op) {
            if (callback(op)) {
                count++;
                count += RecurseHierarchy(op->GetDown(), callback);
                op = op->GetNext();
            }       
        }
        return count;
    }
};
```

<kbd>[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fe915abd953a341)</kbd>

The above change is especially important if you also want to allow `std::function` objects and lambdas to be passed.